# Random letter selection function

Tags: java

I'm trying to write a function that selects a letter based on its frequency count.

Here, the letters a through z have the following frequencies:

```
4778 ,1145 ,1994 ,2075 ,5940 ,762 ,1403 ,1446 ,4263 ,111 ,745 ,3231 ,1625 ,3467 ,3543 ,1455 ,94 ,3678 ,3775 ,3092 ,1883 ,529 ,649 ,139 ,902 ,180
```

The function that generates random letter based on their weighted probability:

```
    public Letter chooseOnWeight(List<Letter> letterNew) {

    int completeWeight = 0;
    int completeWeightUpdated = 0;
    List<Integer> updatedWeightList = new ArrayList<>();
    for (Letter letter : letterNew) {
        updatedWeightList = letter.getWeight();
        for (int i = 0; i < updatedWeightList.size(); i++) {
            completeWeight += updatedWeightList.get(i);

        }
        completeWeightUpdated += completeWeight;
    }

    int countWeightUpdated = 0;
    List<Integer> updatedCountList = new ArrayList<>();
    double r = Math.random() * completeWeight;
    double countWeight = 0.0;
    for (Letter letter : letterNew) {
        updatedCountList = letter.getWeight();
        for (int i = 0; i < updatedWeightList.size(); i++) {
            countWeight += updatedCountList.get(i);
        }
        countWeightUpdated += countWeight;

        if (countWeightUpdated >= r) {
            return letter;
        }
    }
    throw new RuntimeException("Should never be shown.");
}
```

The Letter class, which contains the getWeight() function:

```
public class Letter {
    char name;
    List<Integer> weight;

    public Letter(char name){
        this.name = name;
    }

    public char getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public List<Integer> getWeight() {
        return weight;
    }

    public void setWeight(List<Integer> weight) {
        this.weight = weight;
    }


}
```

Unfortunately the letters being generated are only a-f. For some reason it's not generating any letters after f.

Comment: perhaps show us your `getWeight` method

Comment: Will add getWeight() now

Comment: Create a TreeMap<Integer, Character> , where the key is the cumulated weight of the letter (4778 for A, 4778 + 1145 for B, 4778 + 1145 + 1994 for C, etc.), and the value is the letter. A single pass on the list is needed for this. Generate a random number between 0 and the cumulated weight of Z, and call map.ceilingEntry() to find the letter corresponding to this random number.

Comment: Are you missing anything from your `chooseOnWeight` method? because i don't see you returning anything there

Comment: It returns letter, right under if (countWeightUpdated >= r)

Comment: Excuse me, but I fail to undestand your design, and I suspect your real problem is you don’t fully understand it yourself. If I got it correctly, an object of your `Letter` class contains one letter ( `name`) but the weights of all the letters? This is bound to cause problems. Unless I’m mistaken I think the best solution is a redesign from scratch.

Comment: Why is each letter's `weight` a variable of type `List<Integer>` as opposed to just `Integer`?

Comment: The weights are stored as a List for each length of a word, but here the List<Integer> that is passed in is only one value for the length of a specific word

Comment: Voting to close because it’s not fair to ask a question about code that is incomprehenible and not properly explained.

Comment: Check out my answer, I think you all need to do is set `countWeight` to zero after each iteration of your second for loop.

Comment: I saw it, it worked. Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Reset `countWeight` to `0` after each iteration of the second main for loop in which you iterate through each `Letter` in `letterNew`. Because by not resetting `countWeight`, the expected value of `countWeightUpdated` will be affected after the inner for loop in which you increment `countWeight` by the lengths of the words in `updatedCountList`. After this inner for loop, `countWeightUpdated` should only be incremented by the value of the total weight of the current `Letter` being iterated on, rather than the total weight of all the instances of `Letter` so far. For example, if the total weight of a is 1000, the total weight of b is 1100, and the tota weight of c is 1200, you would want the value of `countWeightUpdated` to be only 1000+1100+1200 = 3300 after iterating through a, b, and c. However, your loop would perform the following addition instead, 1000 + 2100 + 3300 = 8400 because `countWeight` after each iteration will be the total weight of all the letters previously looked at rather than the weight of each letter. 2100 comes from (1000 + 1100) and 3300 comes from (1000 + 1100 + 1200) in this case. As a result, this will limit the range of letters returned to a shorter range. The fix is simple,

```
for (Letter letter : letterNew) {
    updatedCountList = letter.getWeight();
    for (int i = 0; i < updatedWeightList.size(); i++) {
        countWeight += updatedCountList.get(i);
    }
    countWeightUpdated += countWeight;
    countWeight = 0; //THIS IS THE FIX
    if (countWeightUpdated >= r) {
        return letter;
    }
}
```

Also, you have a similar problem in your first main for loop with `completeWeightUpdated` but it's not used much within the method so I didn't mention it since it seemed redundant.